# React Router: How to render element on all routes, except one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I have HTML structure like this:

```html
<body>
  <nav>
     <!--navigation elements -->
  </nav>
  <div className='main'>
     <!--other elements -->
  </div>
  <div className='container'></div>
</body>
```

And routing defined like this:

```js
<Router>
  <Fragment>
    <Navbar />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
    <div className="container">
       <Alert />
       <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
           <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
           <Route exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
       </Switch>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
</Router>
```

The "container" element is present on all routes however I do not want it to be rendered on the "/" route.

How can I stop `<div className="container">` from being rendered on the `"/"` route? I want it to be rendered on all other routes except of `"/"`.

A solution I found, but don't want to use is to explicitly insert the element with `class="container"` in each component that is rendered in my `<Switch>`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you require via [nested routes](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/example-nested-routing) and a ["no match route"](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match).

The idea would be to introduce structure to your routing via nested routes, to restrict rendering of `<div className="container">` to non `/` routes.

To do this, you could extract a component (ie `WithContainer`) that renders a `<Route>` for paths; `/register`, `/login` and `/profiles`, inside of the `<div className="container">`. You would then change your `<Switch>` to now render two routes for the following route cases;

1. A `<Route/>` that renders the `Landing` component on an exact match of `/`
2. A `<Route/>` that renders your new `WithContainer` component on no specific route (ie any path that does not exactly match `/`)

By using the `<Switch>` in this way, it causes the routing behaviour to render either `Landing` or `WithContainer` (but not both) depending on the first matched route. We take advantage of that behaviour to restrict rendering of the `WithContainer` (and in turn, the `<div className="container">` element) for "non `/`" routes.

In code, this approach could be expressed as:

```
const WithContainer = () => (
    <div className="container">
       { /* Wrap routes in container div */ }
       <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
       <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
       <Route exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
    </div>)

const Main = () => (
  <main> 
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Landing}/>
      <Route component={ WithContainer } /> {/* No match route */ }
    </Switch>
  </main>
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It works! Note on specifics: do not forget to implement "Switch"es inside "Router"s of both components.

Answer (score 4):

With the latest version of React Router, you can provide an array of strings for the `path` prop so that a specific route renders on multiple matches:

```
<Route path={['/one', '/two', '/three']} component={SomeComponent} />
```

Here's a link to the relevant documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create a separate component, you can just do this. You need to keep the inner switch as well, if you want to keep the original functionality.

```
// parent switch
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
  // start route wrap!!!
  <Route> 
    <div className="container">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Route>
 // end route wrap!!!
</Switch>
```

You should think of Routes as of any other UI components. You can nest them arbitrarily.